# Getting Date into UK time format correctly before writing to CSV - powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, time, formatting

I have a small bit of code that calculates days elapsed of a computers login.  It works fine and gives me the correct information.  But when the strings are put into the CSV file it displays the date in US time format:  MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss but I want UK: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss  returned to the CSV.

This is the code that gives me the information I need:
Note: The date format in ps displays like this: 04 August 2022 11:21:40

```
##get date into variable
$Date = Get-Date
#Get pc login timestamp into variable
$lastlogon = $Computer.lastlogonTimestamp
##Calculate the days elapsed but this part is really irrelevant for the question.  
$dayslogonelapsed = $Date - $lastlogon
```

Once I am ready to write data to the csv  file the code is as follows:

```
$csvdescriptoutput = 'C:\temp\csvtest.csv'
###Log data to a single variable for CSV. 
$logline = ("$lastlogon;" + "$($dayslogonelapsed.Days)")
###write to CSV
Add-Content -Path $csvdescriptoutput -Value $LogLine
```

When the data is in the log file it displays like this:   07/24/2022 14:07:28 - US format.
When I need this:   24/07/2022 14:07:28  - UK format.
My PC is set to UK time locals and so is my Excel.

Also changing it excel once in the sheet is not an option because the CSV is only looking at strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to `Get-Date` like this:

```sh
$Date = Get-Date -Format 'dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss'
```

This turns the date into a string. To keep `$Date` as a `[DateTime]`, you can also format it on-demand using its `ToString()` method:

```sh
$Date = Get-Date 
$Date.ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss')
```

**Note:**

In order to ensure that the reserved characters `/` and `:` are interpreted literally, independent of locale, escape them by putting a backslash in front of them.

[More info on reserved characters and escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape).

Comment: The date variable would have to maintain it's DateTime data type in order to calculate days.   your command turns it into a string.

Comment: @IainHoward Added a variant that lets you keep `$Date` as `[DateTime]` type.

Comment: This one is throwing an error:
`$Date.ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss')
Error:  Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".

Comment: @IainHoward For me it works with PSVersion 5.1.19041 and CLRVersion 4.0.30319. Which versions do you use (enter `$PSVersionTable`)?

Comment: it's OK,  It's working now.  I was trying to run the command when it was already a string.  Duh!

Comment: Accepted solution:  
`##Convert dates to strings after calculation
$datestr = $Date.ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss')
$lastlogonstr = $lastlogon.ToString('dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss')
`